# <markers></markers> at the top of the XLM file, instead of </markers> at bottom

Tags: php, xml, tags

Good morning! My "reputation" is only "1," but I am hoping someone will help me with this Excessively Annoying Error (ENE). But damned if I can figure out how to make the code properly formatted here. I presume the problem is obvious to every human being but I. Thank you.

Firstly, the XLM result:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<markers></markers>
<marker site_name="Mineral Point Mine" mrds_id="D010915"</marker>
```

Then the code (if I can manage irt):

```
<?php
require("db.php");

$query = $_GET['query']; 

function parseToXML($htmlStr) {
$xmlStr=str_replace('<','&lt;',$htmlStr);
$xmlStr=str_replace('>','&gt;',$xmlStr);
$xmlStr=str_replace('"','&quot;',$xmlStr);
$xmlStr=str_replace("'",'&#39;',$xmlStr);
$xmlStr=str_replace("&",'&amp;',$xmlStr);
return $xmlStr;
}

$doc = new DOMDocument('1.0', 'utf-8');
$doc->formatOutput = true;
$doc->preserveWhiteSpace = false;
$snode = $doc->createElement('markers', '');
$doc->appendChild($snode);

$link = mysqli_connect("localhost", $username, $password, $database);

if (!$link) {
echo "Error: Unable to connect to MySQL." . PHP_EOL;
echo "Debugging errno: " . mysqli_connect_errno() . PHP_EOL;
echo "Debugging error: " . mysqli_connect_error() . PHP_EOL;
exit;
}

$query = "{HIDDEN}";

$result = $link->query($query) or die($link->error);

while ($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {

$node = $doc->createElement("marker","");
$newnode = $doc->appendChild($node);
$newnode->setAttribute("site_name", parseToXML($row['site_name']));
$newnode->setAttribute("mrds_id", parseToXML($row['mrds_id']));
}
$result->close();
echo $doc->saveXML();
?>
```

Comment: You need to append the marker elements to `$snode` as this is the `markers` element.

Comment: Thank you. I thought it already is appended.

Comment: As far as I can tell, I did that already in the code same above.

Answer (score 0):

Adding nodes in DOM is a two step process. You first create them using one of the methods on the document object then you append/insert it using a method on the parent node.

Here is an example without the database calls:

```
$data = [
    [ 
        'site_name' => "Mineral Point Mine", 
        'mrds_id'=> "D010915"
    ]
];

$document = new DOMDocument('1.0', 'UTF-8');
$document->appendChild(
    $markers = $document->createElement('markers')
);

foreach ($data as $row) {
    // create the marker node using document method
    $marker = $document->createElement('marker');
    // add attributes
    $marker->setAttribute('site_name', $row['site_name']);
    $marker->setAttribute('mrds_id', $row['mrds_id']);
    // append to markers parent element
    $markers->appendChild($marker);
}

$document->formatOutput = TRUE;
echo $document->saveXML();
```

Output:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<markers>
  <marker site_name="Mineral Point Mine" mrds_id="D010915"/>
</markers>
```

In general DOM methods take UTF-8 values without escaping. It will escape the special characters during the serialization as needed. Your `parseXML()` calls will lead to double escaping.

Exceptions are the second argument of `DOMDocument::createElement()` and `DOMNode::$nodeValue` assignments. They escape only some characters like `<`. I suggest avoiding them. Append text nodes or use the `DOMNode::$textContent` property.

Demo:

```
$document = new DOMDocument('1.0', 'UTF-8');
$document->appendChild(
    $example = $document->createElement('example')
);
// assign content with special characters
$example->textContent = 'a & b, <>';
echo $document->saveXML();
```

Output:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<example>a &amp; b, &lt;&gt;</example>
```

Comment: Thank you. I will try this. One would think after spending 16 years in IT that I would know this shyte. :-)

Comment: Thank you; it is working. Huh. My code was inelegant. If you are every in Colorado, look me up: I owe you a pre-rolled. :-)